# Find all solutions of the equation $\tan x = 2 + \tan3x$

Tags: trigonometry

So the question is:

Find all solutions of the equation $\tan x = 2 + \tan3x$

where $x\in[0,2\pi]$, expressing your answer as rational multiples of $\pi$.

I've started by expanding $\tan 3x$ using:
$$ \tan(A+B)=(\tan A+\tan B)/(1-\tan A\tan B)$$

where $A$ is $2x$ and $B$ is $x$

I'm not sure if thats the right way to approach this. I also tried making the equation equal to zero.

but I'm pretty stumped. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) for $\tan3x$ , and then solve the [cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) in $t = \tan(x)$ , then compute $x = \arctan t$.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

Just use the same identity to expand $\tan 2x$, and plug into your result. You should get that:
$$\tan 3x = \tan x\cdot \frac{\tan^2 x - 3}{3\tan^2 x -1}$$
And denoting $y=\tan x$, you'll get a cubic equation:
$$(2 -y)(3 y^2 - 1) + y (y^2 - 3) =0$$
$$y^3 - 3y^2 + y + 1 = 0$$
Note that although you have $3$ solutions to $y$, you have $6$ solutions for $x$ in the range you specified. Do you know why?

Comment: I think I've gone wrong somewhere when expanding out tan3_x_. I got 3tanx / 1 -tan^2x